# Как узнать, открыт ли navigationDrawer в android?

Tags: android, java

Как узнать, что боковое меню открыто? Требуется его закрывать, если он открыт при нажатии back, и не закрывать приложение или закрывать приложение, если оно не открыто при нажатии back.

Comment: @metalurgus

    Log.i(tag, drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerLayout) + "");

Это в onBackPressed() тут и выдает ошибку, когда я нажимаю кнопку.
Там 485 строк кода в xml, какая часть именно нужна, там только тексты и лайоты, не понимаю, чем это поможет.

Comment: @eldqs передавать в параметр нужно тот View, который лежит внутри drawerLayout. Тот View, который и есть меню. Обычно это ListView.

Comment: @metalurgus хорошо, я понял спасибо, у меня scrollview, наверное, но я оставлю так, буду прослушивать открытие и закрытие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) описаны 4 метода, позволяющие это проверить. Ссылку на документацию я вместо вас уже нашел. Думаю, найти эти 4 метода вы в состоянии сами. Такой вот вам квест - лекарство от лени.

Comment: спасибо
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html

Comment: @eldqs, если вы собираетеьс таким образом определять, открыт ли drawer, то это глупый костыль.    
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen(android.view.View)

Comment: @metalurgus только что ему передавать в параметрах, Gravity.VISIBLE выдает ошибку

Comment: @eldqs, что, простите??? Gravity.VISIBLE??? у Gravity нету константы VISIBLE. Она есть только у View. У Drawer выставляется гравити. Либо START, либо END.  Соответственно, можно добавить одновременно целых два дровера - слева и справа. Вот эта гравити как раз и определяет, у какого дровера вы хотите получить статус. Но я-то вам дал ссылку на другой метод. В него передается View, у которого надо проверить статус.

Comment: @metalurgus  не то написал сюда, ставлю Gravity.START выдает ошибку, делаю drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerLayout)  тоже выдает ошибку, я не понимаю что конкретно ему передавать и там не описано, еще не настолько разбираюсь чтобы это самому догнать

Comment: @eldqs, покажите ваш XML, там, где DrawerLayout    
И ошибку тоже покажите.

Comment: @metalurgus     java.lang.ClassCastException: 
выдает такое в обоих вариантах, а xml сюда не помещается вот его начало

    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

Comment: @eldqs, можете дополнить вопрос, а не писать в комментарий. Важна какраз та часть, которая не поместилась... А по поводу ошибки - на какой строке кода эта ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Если создавать NavigationDrawer в Андроид Студио этот метод прописывается автоматически onBackPressed.

```
public void onBackPressed() { 
     if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) { 
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     } else { 
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
```

Ну можно работать с ним переделав под свои нужды.